# Why is my unordered list inside a div not rendering correctly?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, html-lists

I have an unordered list inside a div with a background image for each list item. However, the list is not appearing correctly in Internet Explorer 8.

> [Rendered Output http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/7204/screenshotjv.jpg](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/7204/screenshotjv.jpg)

The problem is there is too much space to the left and top of the list. As well as between each list item. I want the list to be completely flush with the image section above it so there's no white space on the left, top, or between each item.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="topimage">
        <center>
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="image"/>
        </center>
    </div>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#top { 
    width: 255px; 
    float:left; 
    margin:3px; 
}

#topimage {
    width: 245px;
    border:1px solid #bcc5c8;
    padding:3px;
}

.list li {
    background-image:url(../images/list_sub.jpg);
    width: 245px;
    height:23px;
    list-style:inside;
    list-style-image:url(../images/listarrow.gif);
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

I've tried setting the margin and padding to zero, but that didn't work. I've also checked to make sure the images don't have extra space around them. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things you can adjust:

1. Wrap your list item contents in spans and apply the list item arrow to the spans instead, give the span a padding-left value slightly larger than the arrow gif's width.
2. Don't use the list-style-image property, just specify a list-style: none; to get left alignment x-browser.  Generally you should just use the background image property for list items instead of the list-style-image, but since you have a background image for li's too, you need the extra span.
3. Don't apply padding to the same elements you apply widths and heights.  They will not render cross-browser.  Instead specify width/height on a parent element and padding on an inner wrapper element.
4. generally you should avoid id rules, they are heavily specific and result in non-reusable style definitions.  They make overriding the style definition difficult.
5. To make the list items touch each other, make sure the line-height specified on them is equal to or less than the height of the elements.  I think the list-item-style will fix it, but double check this setting too.

If that doesn't fix your problem, post a link to the background images and I'll mock up a small example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I edited the original post with some rewritten code. It's not perfect yet, but it's getting better to what I want. I'm not entirely sure how to make the arrows appear using spans. And I'm sure there's some other things that could be better. I didn't know about the "id" thing. Also, I uploaded the background image here: http://i47.tinypic.com/30ry04k.jpg

Comment: For the arrows, just set the background-image of the span to the arrow image.  If you specify a background position of left center, and add padding-left: 30px; the arrow should line up properly.  No worries on the ID practice, it's not very widespread yet.